# CSS scale animation in SVG text-tag not working on Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to have scale animation on an SVG text-tag. But it seems not working on WebKit based browser (Eg, Safari, Chrome iOS).

The word `Test` should show up, but not in Safari:

```css
#text { 
  fill: #333;
  animation: scaleIn 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
  from {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="none">
  <text x="0" y="0" alignment-baseline="central" dominant-baseline="central" id="text" text-anchor="middle">
    Test
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Best to report Safari bugs to the [webkit bugtracker](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: It works on chrome (84.0.4147.89). However, safari did not work for me either. The animations do work but not in the context of svg-text-elements as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself. I found that wrapping the text element in a group tag and then applying your id to the group tag will fix your issue. I tested it on your code and it works a treat. Good luck!

```css
#text { 
  fill: #333;
  animation: scaleIn 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
  from {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="none">
  <g id="text">
    <text x="0" y="0" alignment-baseline="central" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle">
      Test
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```